# Obter número de seguidores no instagram com PHP

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Tenho o seguinte código:

```
$username = 'makeup.pro.br';
        $response = @file_get_contents( "https://www.instagram.com/$username/?__a=1" );

        if ( $response !== false ) {
            $data = json_decode( $response, true );
            if ( $data !== null ) {
                $full_name = $data['graphql']['user']['full_name'];
                $follower  = $data['graphql']['user']['edge_followed_by']['count'];
                echo "{$full_name} have {$follower} followers.";
            }
        } else {
            echo 'Username not found.';
        }

        die();
```

Ele funciona perfeitamente em localhost. Porém quando coloco no ar, ele não trás nada, não funciona.

Não estou conseguindo achar o motivo de não funcionar no ar.

Comment: Tira o `@` do `@file_get_contents`. Não faz sentido você omitir qualquer mensagem de erro quando você não sabe o que está errado.

Comment: Já fiz isso. Não funcionou também.

Comment: Há alguma mensagem de erro nos logs do servidor? Qual é o valor de `$response` e `$data`?

Comment: Quando dou um echo $response; em localhost, ele me trás um json com as informações da página, mas no ar, ele apenas me trás uma página em branco com o símbolo do Instagram e nada mais. Será que pode ser alguma configuração do meu servidor na nuvem?

Comment: Ao invés do `echo` use `var_dump($response); exit;`

Comment: Com o var_dump, me retornou isso: string(38297) " "

Comment: Ok, agora olhe o código fonte da página. Está retornando um HTML ou XML que o navegador está tentando processar.

Comment: Ta tentando processar um HTML: string(38304) "<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" class="no-js not-logged-in client-root">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">

        <title>
Login • Instagram
</title>

        
        <meta name="robots" content="noimageindex, noarchive"> ...

Answer (score 1):

Consegui resolver.

Entrei em contato com o suporte da minha hospedagem e me disseram para fazer o comando dessa forma:

```
$response = file_get_contents($value->instagram_link . "?__a=1", false, stream_context_create(['socket' => ['bindto' => '0: 0']]));
```